# GameKit peer to peer wifi without wireless router?

Tags: ios, wifi, gamekit

Thanks in advance for any thoughts about this.  I'm looking for a way to do realtime inter-app communication in iOS via wi-fi (I need about 150 ft range and don't think bluetooth offers this) and wonder about the peer-to-peer connectivity offered by GameKit which, apparently offers both bluetooth and wi-fi connectivity.  My question is: must participating devices be members of an available wireless network (via a wireless router) or is this connectivity truly peer-to-peer requiring no router?

I understand Wi-fi Direct is coming and would likely be an option.  Just wondering if I can do this utilizing services available in iOS today.

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 1):

A router is required for Wi-Fi connectivity. Bluetooth connectivity does not need one.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  That's kinda what I expected to hear.  Am I correct to say that there's currently no way to write an iOS app that implements peer-to-peer connectivity without the need for routers, etc. and also functions at a range of 150 feet?

Comment: iOS devices don't even have the necessary firmware to implement an ad-hoc network, as far as I'm aware.